# View a huge file from the webbrowser

Tags: php

I have a 150MB txt file of server logs. Probably with PHP, I want to view 100 lines at a time starting from the end of the file. When the user clicks "Pevious 100 lines" or something, the next set of 100 is loaded.

What would be the best way to approach this?

I've seen these ajax chat widgets that have a similar feature, how do they do this task?

Comment: http://www.geekality.net/2011/05/28/php-tail-tackling-large-files/ first page on Google, query "php tail"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the linux commands like head and tail for this

```
 `tail -n 100 filename`
```